# select where data1 and Data2 is zero MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, where-clause

I want select the rows where

1. Data1 and Data2 is not 0 for one ID
2. and also select all the Code 5

Table 1 -

```
ID  Code    Data1       Data2
A   1           0       0
A   2           0       11.68
A   3           0.97    3.51
B   1           0       0
B   2           0.15    5.35
B   3           0.58    7.39
C   5           0       0
```

So I want the output table as under:

```
ID  Code    Data1   Data2
A   2       0       11.68
A   3       0.97    3.51
B   2       0.15    5.35
B   3       0.58    7.39
C   5       0       0
```

I wrote the query as below,but it didnt work, can someone help me.

```
select ID, CODE, DATA1, DATA2  from table1 where  (DATA1 !=0 and DATA2 !=0) or Code =5
```

Comment: One question, here record for ID=A and Code=2 is considered in result . because Data1 is 0 but Data2 has value right?

Comment: @Maulik Kansara yes correct

Comment: `where DATA1 !=0 OR DATA2 !=0 OR Code =5` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the data setup this will also solve the problem

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ([ID] varchar(1), [Code] int, [Data1] numeric(22,6), [Data2]  numeric(22,6))
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    ([ID], [Code], [Data1], [Data2])
VALUES
    ('A', 1, 0, 0),
    ('A', 2, 0, 11.68),
    ('A', 3, 0.97, 3.51),
    ('B', 1, 0, 0),
    ('B', 2, 0.15, 5.35),
    ('B', 3, 0.58, 7.39),
    ('C', 5, 0, 0)
;
select ID, CODE, DATA1, DATA2  from table1 a where  Data1 <> 0 or Data2 <> 0
or code=5
```

output

```
ID  Code    Data1   Data2
A   2       0       11.68
A   3       0.97    3.51
B   2       0.15    5.35
B   3       0.58    7.39
C   5       0       0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select ID, CODE, DATA1, DATA2  from table1 a where  
a.Code = 5 OR
NOT EXISTS
(
 SELECT 1 FROM table1  b WHERE a.Id = b.Id AND b.Data1 = 0 AND b.Data2 = 0
)
```

Comment: thanks for quick reply. However that returned null value for me, can you please tell me what I am doing incorrectly. Also the condition for code 5 is not addressed in above query.

Comment: May be " for one ID" change to "for one Code"?

Comment: If I change the ID to Code the entire logic of the data will be incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

As per the result set, i can observer that record will be considered if anyone from Data1 and Data2 is greater than 0. And you are trying to get data with the filter as both are not zero. use `OR` operator instead of `And`.

```
select ID, CODE, DATA1, DATA2  from table1 where  (DATA1 !=0 or DATA2 !=0) or Code =5
```

Comment: Not an issue @Duffer

Answer (score 0):

select * from Table1 where Data1<>0 and Data2 <>0 or Code=5

Answer (score 0):

hope this helps!!

```
    CREATE TABLE #table1(ID VARCHAR(10),Code INT,Data1 float,Data2 float)

    INSERT INTO #table1
    SELECT 'A',1,0,0 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'A',2,0,11.68 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'A',3,0.97,3.51 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'B',1,0,0 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'B',2,0.15,5.35 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'B',3,0.58,7.39 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'C',5,0,0

    ;with cte
    AS
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*) OVER(partition by id)c,
        * from #table1
    )

    Select id,code,Data1,Data2 from cte 
    where 1=(CASE WHEN c=1 THEN 1
                  WHEN Data1<>0 or Data2 <>0 then 1
                  ELSE 0
              END)

    Drop table #table1
```